# How to configure map for all ttk widgets except TButton?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

I am creating a GUI with Tkinter and ttk, and I'm trying to create a custom `map` to make ttk widgets blue on hover. I could apply that to all widgets with passing `"."` as the first argument to `ttk.Style().map(...)`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


root = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style()
style.map(".", background=[("active", "blue")])

button = ttk.Button(root, text="An example button")
button.pack()
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

But now I want to exclude `TButton` from this query. That is, I need to make all widgets **but** `TButton` blue on hover. How can I do that?

Passing ".!TButton" as well as "!TButton" instead of "." has no effect.

Comment: @CoolCloud, thank you very much :) Somehow, I didn't think about overriding the mapping. Would you like to add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is a root style whose name is '.'. To change some feature's default appearance for every widget, you can configure this style. For example, let's suppose that you want all text to be 12-point Helvetica (unless overriden by another style or font option).

So we can override it by simply adding another style:

```
style.map('TButton',background=[('active','#f0f0f0')])
```

Keep a note that you might want to do this for every style that you wish to set to default too.

Take a read [here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-style-layer.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)